# topology : cutting outer holes?

Tags: topology

I'm trying to achieve a similar mechanical ring component (the basis here in the photo below, surrounded in red), and I don't clearly understand how to model the central circular part, the ring where the screw's head are.

[image: screw support]

Any ideas on how to do this kind of topology ?
Thx in advance !

Comment: Add support edges, that will help you retain the shape so that the subsurf modifier doesn't do unwanted rounding

Comment: Horizontally you mean ?

Comment: I can't tell from the image what the piece in the background looks like.

Comment: Actually I don't clearly understand how to have this kind of "outer of the ring" hole topology (but thx for the tip, it solve the unwanted roundings issue)

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add more information, I'm confused on what you want to do.

Comment: @Aleph maybe try to assign a different material (with a different color) to the part of the mesh where you wish to "cut a hole", I can't get what you want, too...

Comment: Sorry guys, my initial question was unclear, I rephrased it, hope it makes more sense now. In one word I just want to know how to model the circular part, the ring where the screw's head are (as no one is perfect, I'm french, sorry for my english !)